# What am I doing wrong in this loop?

Tags: java, loops, boolean

So for I am trying to make a boolean method that checks if an inputed string is a positive integer. It will return true if it is a positive integer and false if it is anything else. Here is my code:

```
public static boolean isPositiveInteger(String input) {
        int stringLength = input.length();
        int index = stringLength-1;

        while(index>0) {
            index--;

            if(input.charAt(0) != '-' && input.charAt(index) >= '0' && 
               input.charAt(index) <= '9') {
                return true;
            } 
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

When the input is the string "fish33" the method will return true instead of false. Why is that?

Comment: check carefully where you return `true` and `false`.

Comment: Your function does: if the last character is a number then return tru, else return false.

Comment: You have to check the entire string before you can return `true`. You can return `false` the instant you encounter an invalid character.

Comment: @daddykom Technically it checks the second to last character.

Comment: @youassassin: You are right. I did not saw that.

Answer (score 1):

Your `while` loop executes only once - `return` will stop execution. Moreover, you start with second to last, not with last character. Replace your code with this one:

```
public static boolean isPositiveInteger(String input) {
    int stringLength = input.length();
    int index = stringLength;

    // special case when input is empty string
    if (index == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    while(index > 0) {
        index--;

        // if some of the characters is not digit, return false
        if !(input.charAt(index) >= '0' && 
           input.charAt(index) <= '9') {
            return false;
        }
    }
    // if the while loop does not find any other character, return true
    return true;
}
```

Comment: IMHO, it should return false in case of empty string.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

There is no point to make so many manipulations, it can be solved in few lines

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(isPositiveInteger("1"));
    System.out.println(isPositiveInteger("abc"));
}


public static boolean isPositiveInteger(String input) {
    try {
        Integer i = Integer.parseInt(input);
        return i > 0;
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: I bet this wouldn't compile ;-)

Comment: @Evilguy you forgot to add semi-colon `;` in the first draft. Hence, the comment. Try being appreciative if someone helps you to correct your mistakes instead of taking their input and then trying desperately to insult them

Comment: @BalwinderSingh IMHO I thought people are here to help, not to make some noise, if you spotted that semi-colon you could let me know, instead of downrating the answer. yeah missed the exception if somebody enters invalid string. but it is still better than looping thought string, which is toootally unprofessional. If you would get this question on interview with positive rank answer they would laugh...

Comment: @Evilguy So nice of you to delete your earlier comment and come up with this one. Puts this whole conversation in different light. The comment you deleted was arrogant and you were trying to insult. That failed so you deleted your comment and came with this holier than thou approach. My 1st comment is still correct and it was more put across in a funny sort of way (unless you missed the smiley at the end of that). Also how do you know that I downrated? I just put the comment in and there are 3 guys who downrated it. So it can be anyone. Try to improve your answer instead